# USB 3.0 HDMI capture card

Tags: hdmi, vlc, video-capture-card

I bought this cheap Magewell knock-off USB capture card on Amazon that said it had support for V4L2 and VLC support with kernel builds 2.6.38+. It is a H.264 hardware encoder (chroma I422) and I'm using an HDMI splitter to strip the HDCP signaling.

So far I have consistently gotten audio throughput, but was only able to achieve video once (accidently), and their terrible customer support won't even respond to a simple question.

Anyhow, does anyone have any tricks they have used to get a USB capture card to play well with VLC? I am a fairly advanced user, but I finally admitted defeat and figured I'd reach out to the users here before I send this heap back to the seller.

Comment: Well, I waited 6 days. Guess it's time to bump.

Comment: Hey Alisenby - did you ever get this working?  I'm looking for a VidCap device for Ubuntu, would like to know if this Magewell one works....

Comment: No, I abandoned it... didn't feel like throwing away any more money just to troubleshoot it. I suspect that I needed an HDMI 2.0 (HDCP 2.2) splitter to strip the encryption, rather than my HDMI 1.3 splitter.